# Semantic UI Stackable Grid - make use of white space / dynamically get real width of stackable grid

Tags: css, meteor, semantic-ui

Maybe I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be, maybe it's not possible, but... ideally if there is white space I would like to utilise it.

I'm using Semantic UI stackable grid, if I made the browser width in the example screenshot below just a bit wider another 'post' would appear to the right and there would be 3 columns.  Perfect!

I want to know if there is a way to dynamically calculate the 'unused space' so that if it's over a certain amount I can display a small item in that space.
If the user then made the browser a bit wider, another post would appear to the right to make 3 columns and the small item would disappear.

A point in the right direction would be amazing, can I dynamically calculate the number of columns and therefore work out their total width compared with window width??  Any other way you can think of achieving this?

Thanks, Lezlea

My site is in beta testing: http://fishtag.world/

[image]
<sub>(source: [lezlea.co.uk](http://www.lezlea.co.uk/fishtag/todelete/whitespace.png))</sub>

Comment: Learn about media queries, another way would be to use JS but i think you can achieve this with CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

Stackable Grid should keep your columns spanning the available space and on smaller screens it should make all 100% (https://jsfiddle.net/ryan_whitlie/2sLw5bon/), but yours seem to be wrapping before you hit smaller screen size. You perhaps have some margin applied to the columns?

To achieve what you are asking for, you would be better to split that section into 2 columns, left being say 75% the full width and the right at 25%. Showing the 'posts' in the left and your other content in the right. Then when the screen size gets to a certain size, hide the right column and only show your posts using CSS media queries:

```
@media(min-width: 600px) {
    .posts {
        width: 75%;
    }
    .aside {
        width: 25%;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

This will apply widths and show (`display: block;`) the two columns on any screen/device with a width of 600px or more.

Check out the working version here and feel free to change the `600px` value
https://jsfiddle.net/ryan_whitlie/cg9p3kuw/